# gridgain cache access performance: sql vs cache.getKey?

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

I am accessing gridgain cache for large number of keys. I have two option to get values:

1. access `gridgain` cache and get value for each key in an `IgniteClosure` and return the result.
2. execute `org.apache.ignite.cache.query.SqlQuery` on the cache and then get the result.

Below are my questions:

1. What is the recommended/optimal way in this scenario?
2. Why one could be slower than others (like query parsing might be an extra overhead).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing a `getAll(Set<K> keys)` operation? Sounds like it suits your use case perfectly.

If you have even more data, consider collocated processing with local ScanQuery or map/reduce ExecuteTask/ExecuteJob.

Answer (score 0):

If primary keys are known in advance, then use key-value APIs such as `cache.get` or `cache.getAll`. If those records are further to be used as part of a calculation then try to turn the calculation to a compute task and execute it one the nodes that store primary copies of the keys -- you can use `compute.affinityRun` methods for that.

SQL is favorable if the primary keys are not known in advance or if you need to filter data with the `WHERE` clause or do joins between tables.